# How can I leave a voice and speech recognition program in the background? I'm mainly using the Androidhelper library

Tags: python, pydroid

Hello I was making a program about speech and speech recognition, but I don't know how to leave it in the background, I'm mainly using Androidhelper as the main source, besides, there is some other way of voice recognition in qlpython

Comment: What does this have to do with PyDroid? BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please takje the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.